# Why does haskell force to always type the generic types?

Tags: haskell, types

Lets say we have:

```
data Data a b c = Build (a,b,c) deriving Show

foo :: Data a b c -> Data a b c
foo d = d

main = print $ foo $ Build (1, 1, "a")
```

Is there any way to avoid writting `a b c` for each use of Data type?

Using the type, something like:

```
foo :: Data -> Data
foo d = d
```

Comment: Actually you do not *have* to write type signatures at all. If you omit them, Haskell will derive them for you.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I know about that, lets say apart from that. Will edit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, sure:

```
foo :: d ~ Data a b c => d -> d
```

Comment: @DanielSanchez No, that's an [equality constraint](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/equality-constraints.html). Basically it says the type `d` must be equal to `Data a b c`, but you could have more complex constraints like `A a b c ~ B d e f`. Haskell *does* have type synonyms, but you either have to make them rank 2, or add the parameters.

Comment: @DanielSanchez I don't think you should use _any_ of these suggestions. I think you should write out the type variables. DanielWagner is an expert (you're welcome); as a Haskell learner I think you should learn how to use its programming model first and foremost. That means steering clear of advanced features like type equalities.

Answer (score 8):

```
data Data a b c = Build (a,b,c) deriving Show
type D a t a' = Data a t a'

foo :: D a t a' -> D a t a'
foo d = d
```

Aliases are fun, but this isn't intended as a serious answer.

Edit: A serious version, if you know a common monomorphic type then aliases become useful:

```
type AppData = Data AppState AppValue AppResult
foo :: AppData -> AppData
...
```

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: That's very inventive, great job!

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap up the polymorphic type in a `type` synonym.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

type d ~> d' = forall a b c. d a b c -> d' a b c

foo :: Data ~> Data
foo d = d
```

It's probably simpler just to write out the type variables though.

Comment: i dont fully understand this, could you bring me light from a web link or something please? thanks

Comment: @DanielSanchez: Briefly, when you have type variables in a signature, they implicitly have *quantifiers* that define their scope, so `foo :: Data a b c -> Data a b c` is implicitly `forall a b c. Data a b c -> Data a b c`. The type `Data ~> Data` expands to the same thing, `forall a b c. Data a b c -> Data a b c`, by replacing `d` and `d'` with `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Data` is not a type but a type constructor. If you a prefer a function which takes 3 types and returns a new type. Type constructors can also types other type constructors as argument example

```
  data D d a= D (d a a a)
```

I can then use your `Data` (without argument)  `D Data a`...